# Comparing value of selected radio with jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, forms

I'm able to get the value of the selected radio button with jQuery. The problem is when I'm trying to compare that string with another string. It's simply not working, and I'm not getting any console errors.

Here are the buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="contact-type" id="contact-type-1" value="contact_us" checked="checked" class="radioContact">
<label for="contact-type-1"> Contact Us</label><br>

<input type="radio" name="contact-type" id="contact-type-2" value="book_appt" class="radioContact">
<label for="contact-type-2"> Book an Appointment</label><br>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$('.radioContact').click( function () {
    if( $( this ).val() == "book_apt" ){
        $( '.bottom-form' ).show();
    } else {
        $( '.bottom-form' ).hide();
    }
});
```

It's always returning `false` and will only hide the div, never show it. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Use [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event on radio instead of `click`
2. To get the selected radio value use [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector
3. Use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to toggle an element

Code:

```
$('.radioContact').change(function () {
    $('.bottom-form').toggle($('.radioContact:checked').val() === 'book_apt');
});
```